# Meaning 'Their house was small for the lumber to build it had to be carried by wagon many miles'

Tags: meaning

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence from Wonderful Wizard of Oz:

> Their house was small for the lumber to build it had to be carried by wagon many miles.

I check my vocabulary: Lumber is a derivative of a tree, but  the expression above is unclear for me. Particularly this expression: *house .. for the lumber to build it had to be carried*.

Answer (score 3):

You’re missing a bit of the text from the phrase.

Their house **was small**, for the lumber to build it had to be carried by wagon many miles.

This means they only built a house that suited their needs, because the wood had to be carried a long way to their budding spot.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: The original question has been edited, making the answers here sound a little strange. It now shows an actual quotation, even though it's still missing a comma and there is still not a complete citation.

---

The problem is that you have not provided an actual quotation—and what you have provided is wrong.

From [*The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/43936/43936-h/43936-h.htm) by L. Frank Baum (emphasis mine):

> Their house **was small,** for the lumber to build it had to be carried by wagon many miles.

It means that they were limited to the amount of lumber they could carry on their wagon; therefore, the resulting house was small.